# Excel VBA iterate through triplets and adding negative sign

Tags: excel, vba

I have this lat and long string for a kml file and I would like to change all of the longitude values negative in the following string below.

I thought the easiest way was to put them into triplets and iterate through each line and add a negative sign to the first number.

```
latlong = "1.48638,54.9621256516623,0 1.48521523184216,54.9621324923351,0 1.48405081848398,54.9621530122697,0 1.48288711461705,54.9621872052157,0 1.48172447471685,54.9622350607575"

latlong = Replace(latlong, " ", vbCrLf)
```

From

```
1.48638,54.9621256516623,0

1.48521523184216,54.9621324923351,0

.....
```

to

```
-1.48521523184216,54.9621324923351,0

-1.48405081848398,54.9621530122697,0
```

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
latlong = "-" & latlong
latlong = Replace(latlong, " ", vbCrLf & "-")
```

Comment: Nice one Ravi! This addresses OP need and does that efficiently. +1